# How to read a key from app setting file when value is know?

Tags: c#, xml

I am developing an application in .NET Framework using C#, in my application I have the necessity of getting a value from an XML file. I have written the following code, to get the value when the key is provided by searching for the key in the XML file.

```
        XmlDocument appSettingsDoc = new XmlDocument();
        appSettingsDoc.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config");
        XmlNode node = appSettingsDoc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings");
        XmlElement value = (XmlElement)node.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//add[@key='{0}']", key));
        return (value.GetAttribute("value"));
```

But I am unable to get the key name when the value is given, for example, if the file contains

```
                    `<add key="keyname" value="keyvalue" />`
```

and if I provide "keyvalue" I want to get "keyname". I know that I am reading from the appconfig file and there is an other way also(i.e using configurationmanager) but I want to read it using XML.
Please help me out.

Thanks,

Bibhu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this method

```
   private static string readConfig(string value)
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
        System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection ass = config.AppSettings;
        foreach (System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement item in ass.Settings)
        {
            if (item.Value == value)
                return item.Key;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this not work?

```
XmlDocument appSettingsDoc = new XmlDocument();
appSettingsDoc.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + ".config");
XmlNode node = appSettingsDoc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings");
XmlElement value = (XmlElement)node.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//add[@value='{0}']", value));
return (value.GetAttribute("key"));
```

Note that this system assumes that each value in your appSettings is unique, or else you'll only get the first key with the specified value.

If I were implementing this, by the way, I would just construct a new dictionary from the ConfigurationManager.AppSettings dictionary, using values as keys and keys as values. Reading the appSettings section of the config file via the XML interface when it is already parsed for you into a dictionary is definitely a code smell.

Answer (score 1):

To find key based on value you can still use the `ConfigurationManager` class, can't see any reason to replace it with your own code.

So, sample code would be:

```
string myKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.AllKeys.ToList().FirstOrDefault(key =>
{
    return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] == "keyvalue";
});
```

Comment: Please read the question. The question regards how to get a key name when a value is provided.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think you have not read the last line, over there i have clearly mentioned that I know how to get it using ConfigurationManager.AppSettings. But I dont want to use it.

Comment: @Bibhu sorry but I really can't see any reason why not use that class, so I'll leave this fixed answer for the sake of others who do want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
<add key="keyname" value="keyvalue" />
```

use

```
<add key="keyvalue" value="keyname" />
```

Thats how its meant to be.

Answer (score 0):

Do it using XPath query, don't have time to mock one up now.

Answer (score 0):

try to use Linq to XMl like this

```
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load(@"XmlFile.xml");
var q = from c in loaded.Descendants("add")
        where (String)c.Attribute("value") == "value1"
        select c;
foreach(var item in q)
     Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("key").Value);
```